# Refresh Sheet worksheet using export-excel module of powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am using Export-excel module in PowerShell, where i am appending a new worksheet(sheet 2) in previously defined excel (sheet 1). The new worksheet contains data and the previously defined worksheet contains pivot table. After inserting data, i would like to refresh the data of sheet 1, but i am not getting any option to refresh the sheet using export-excel.
Any help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: any help please

Comment: If you are referring to the ```ImportExcel``` module I'm using, then no, it appears that you need Excel install to play with data queries. With Excel installed you can use ```New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application``` to do a ```Workbook.RefreshAll()```